# Suppress and handle stderr error output in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, networking, ip, stderr, smb

I wanted to capture SMB shares using PowerShell, but this doesn't work

```
# Cannot use CIM as it throws up WinRM errors.
# Could maybe use if WinRM is configured on all clients, but this is not a given.
$cim = New-CimSession -ComputerName $hostname
$sharescim = Get-SmbShare -CimSession $cim
```

So this led me to another method using net view and this is fairly ok if the host is Windows

```
# This method uses net view to collect the share names (including hidden shares like C$) into an array
# https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/view-all-shares-remote-machine-powershell
try { $netview = $(net view \\$hostname /all) | select -Skip 7 | ?{$_ -match 'disk*'} | %{$_ -match '^(.+?)\s+Disk*'|out-null ; $matches[1]} }
catch { $netview = "No shares found" }
```

So, if the host is Linux, I get an error, and as you can see, I am trying above to suppress that error with try / catch, but this fails.

Obviously, this is because 'net view' is CMD so is not controllable by try / catch. So my question is: how can I a) suppress the system error below?, and b) *handle* this error when it happens (i.e. throw a "This host is not responding to 'net view'" or something instead of the error)?

```
System error 53 has occurred.
The network path was not found.
```

Comment: As an aside: you don't need `$(...)` to run an external program; in short: `$(...)` is only needed in expandable strings (`"..."`) or to embed whole statements in other statements.

Comment: Another aside: `net.exe` is a _console application_, and as such unrelated to any particular shell. As a console application, it has only two output streams at its disposal: stdout (standard output), for data, and stderr (standard error) for error messages and/or status messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Stderr (standard error) output from *external programs* is not integrated with PowerShell's error handling**, primarily because this stream is not only used to communicate *errors*, but also *status* information.
(You should therefore only infer success vs. failure of an external-program call from its *exit code*, as reflected in `$LASTEXTICODE`<sup>[1]</sup>).

However, you can *redirect* stderr output, and redirecting it to `$null` (`2>$null`) silences it<sup>[2]</sup>:

```
$netview = net view \\$hostname /all 2>$null | ...
if (-not $netview) { $netview = 'No shares found' }
```

---

<sup>[1] Acting on a nonzero exit code, which by convention signals failure, is also not integrated into PowerShell's error handling as of v7.1, but fixing that is being proposed in [this RFC](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/261/files).</sup>

<sup>[2] Up to PowerShell 7.1.x, any `2>` redirection unexpectedly *also* records the stderr lines in the automatic `$Error` collection. This problem has been corrected in v7.1

As an unfortunate side effect, in versions up to v7.0, a `2>` redirection can also throw a script-terminating error if `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` happens to be in effect, if at least one stderr line is emitted.</sup>